# Issue while not using SlideMenuControllerSwift as the first viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, hamburger-menu

I am trying to use the third party `SlideMenuControllerSwift`for displaying a hamburger menu. I am able to display the hamburger menu properly when it is loaded in the very first `viewcontroller` that comes up. But in case I have a login screen for example and after the login screen, I navigate to another screen and when I try to show the slide menu in this screen, I am not able to do so properly.

In the example from github for `SlideMenuControllerSwift`, the required screens are loaded in the `AppDelegate` and called in the `AppDelegate` itself from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Following this idea, even if I call the method that is called in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from the `viewDidLoad` of my screen of choice (where I want to display the hamburger menu), the hamburger menu is not showing up in that screen. I do get the logo of the hamburger menu displayed on top left but it is not clickable. Please help...:)

Answer (score 1):

When user login try this.

```
SlideMenuOptions.contentViewDrag = true
SlideMenuOptions.leftViewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.75

let contentVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
let leftVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController
let slideVC = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: contentVC, leftMenuViewController: leftVC)
slideVC.view.clipsToBounds = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(slideVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I am able to go to the next viewcontroller without any issues but I am not able to see the hamburger menu icon at the top left. On the top left, I am just getting the default back button of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Replace pushViewController with PresentViewController ,

```
let rootController = UIStoryboard.init(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"HomeVC") as! HomeViewController

        SlideMenuOptions.leftViewWidth = 280.0

        SlideMenuOptions.contentViewScale = 1.0

        let leftMenu = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "slidingMenuNavigationController") as! UINavigationController

        let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: rootController, leftMenuViewController: leftMenu)

        present(slideMenuController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: If we replace pushViewController with presentViewController, then Back button is gone. We cannot see the back Button.